# How to return a widget before VideoPlayerController.file().initialize().whenComplete(); has completed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to return a widget in a `FutureBuilder()`. Here is what my code looks like:

FutureBuilder:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context)
{
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Content'),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: downloadRequest(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot)
        {
          if(snapshot.hasData)
          {
            if(arguments["file_type"] == "video/mp4")
            {
              _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(new File(snapshot.data));

              _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

              _initializeVideoPlayerFuture.whenComplete(() => buildVideo());
            }
            else
            {
              return Center(
                child:
                  Text("Invalid data type")
                );
            }
          }
          else
          {
            return SizedBox(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
            );
          }
        }
    ),
  );
```

buildVideo:

```
Future<Column> buildVideo() async
  {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                _controller.pause();
              }
              else {
                _controller.play();
              }
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons
                .play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
}
```

The problem is that since this code runs within `FutureBuilder()`, it requires a `widget` to be returned. If I run the above code it throws an error.

How can I display a Spinner widget whilst I wait for `_initializeVideoPlayerFuture` to complete?

Comment: `FutureBuilder` official documentation has a sample code on how to use it

Comment: @pskink Do you understand what I am trying to do though? The `FutureBuilder` class documentation does not have an example when using `VideoPlayerController.file().initialize().whenComplete();`

Comment: call your all async tasks (downloadRequest followed by _controller.initialize) inside some `async` method and pass its `Future` return value to your `FutureBuilder`

Comment: That's a much better solution. Thank you.